# Mould on the inside of a bitumen corrugated sheet

Tags: roof, mold

Attached to the end of our house is a small shed. It has four (newly built) brick walls and a [bitumen corrugated sheet roof](http://m.wickes.co.uk/mt/www.wickes.co.uk/roofing/bitumen-corrugated-sheets+trims/icat/rsbitumenroof/#navrsbitumenroof). The shed was finished about eight months ago and is fairly waterproof. However, in the last few months we've noticed, what I presume, is mould on the inside of the [roof](http://m.wickes.co.uk/mt/www.wickes.co.uk/roofing/bitumen-corrugated-sheets+trims/icat/rsbitumenroof/#navrsbitumenroof). Although it appears dry to touch, all our belongings are covered in drops of brown liquid (from the roof).

Could the mould be caused by a lack of ventilation or is there another plausible reason? BTW, I'm calling it mould for lack of a better term.

**Response to the comments**

I don't think it's tar (surely tar would be black?) Also, we've had this type of shed roof before (the old shed collapsed last year due to a burst water main), and this is just a replacement. Admittedly, the brick work is far superior in this shed.

**Some pictures**

1. The first picture is of the inside of the roof. All the roof is now like this. When new, it was black.
2. The second picture shows some of the brown drops of liquid on a box.

[image: The underside of the roof.]
[image: A box with drops from the roof.]

Comment: What are you looking at on the inside of the roof? The bottoms of the corrugated panels? Is there sheathing? A ceiling? If it's just the panels, could the drops be melted tar dripping?

Comment: It's coming from the inside of the roof. Here is a picture of the roof: http://m.wickes.co.uk/mt/www.wickes.co.uk/roofing/bitumen-corrugated-sheets+trims/icat/rsbitumenroof/#navrsbitumenroof

Comment: What makes you think it's mold? Could it be the tar, itself? Unless that's a super air-tight shed, I can't imagine there being enough moisture, nor that being a surface mold would thrive on.

Comment: @DA01 It's not what I expect the tar to look like (see new pictures).

Comment: I had a leak near my chimney once, whoever installed the roof did not use flashing only tar. Anyway the water that leaked through was a similar brown color, not black as you might expect. So I wouldn't rule that out. Is this localized to a small area, or is it throughout the entire shed?

Comment: The entire shed.

Comment: the coloration and pattern definitely makes it _look_ like mold. can you take a cotton swab and scrape some off or is the coloration inside/part of the roof? also, if you have no ventilation, it may (or may not) be a good idea to to take out some bricks in the top rows. maybe every 4th or 5th or something to give it an aesthetic appearance (as well as functional)..

Comment: @jberger When I swab a piece of cotton wool, the wool is stain free.

Comment: the top side looks normal then? is the top side a different finish (e.g. waterproofing)? in any event, [ventilation is a good idea](http://ideas.reliableremodeler.com/Article.aspx?Title=Keeping-Dry-with-Storage-Shed-Ventilation&AC=6&ID=1876)..

Comment: Is there a lot of moisture in the shed? Have you ever walked in and seen beaded water on the ceiling? My thought is that moisture is condensing on the ceiling, picking up some contaminants, and then dripping from the ceiling.  To rule out mold, you should be able to purchase a mold test kit at your local home improvement store or online.

Comment: @Tester101 It turns out that moisture was the problem. The water beaded on the ceiling and dripped down. If you make it an answer, then I'll accept. The moisture only return in the winter :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that moisture was the problem. The water beaded on the ceiling and dripped down. The shed needed additional ventilation.

Answer (score 2):

It most certainly looks like tar residue to me... There are multiple latex paints that you could use to seal the tar in or you could attach a polyurethane sheeting of at least 3mil to the underside of the roof to protect your belongings.